# PyTorch datasets: ImageFolder and subfolder filtering

Tags: python, pytorch

I would like to use [ImageFolder](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#imagefolder) to create an Image Dataset.

My current image directory structure looks like this:

```
/root
-- train/
---- 001.jpg
---- 002.jpg
---- ....
-- test/
---- 001.jpg
---- 002.jpg
---- ....
```

**I would like to have a dataset dedicated to training data, and a dataset dedicated to test data.**

As I understand, doing so:

```py
dataset = ImageFolder(root='root/train')
```

does not find any images.

Doing

```py
dataset = ImageFolder(root='root')
```

find images but `train` and `test` images are just scrambled together.

`ImageFolder` has argument `loader` but I did not manage to find any use-case for it.

**How can I discriminate images in the root folder according to the subfolder they belong to?**

Comment: are there subfolders (denoting classes) inside both train/test? your figure doesn't look like so [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder)

Comment: You should try doing `dataset = ImageFolder(root='root/train/')`. Notice the extra / after train.

Comment: @akshayk07 The error remains the same -> `Found 0 files in subfolders of: root/train/`

Comment: @syltruong Maybe try `/root/train/`

Answer (score 3):

`ImageFolder` expects the data folder (the one that you pass as `root`) to contain subfolders representing the classes to which its images belong. Something like this:

```
data/
├── train/
|   ├── class_0/
|   |   ├── 001.jpg
|   |   ├── 002.jpg
|   |   └── 003.jpg
|   └── class_1/
|       ├── 004.jpg
|       └── 005.jpg
└── test/
    ├── class_0/
    |   ├── 006.jpg
    |   └── 007.jpg
    └── class_1/
        ├── 008.jpg
        └── 009.jpg
```

Having the above folder structure you can do the following:

```
train_dataset = ImageFolder(root='data/train')
test_dataset  = ImageFolder(root='data/test')
```

Since you don't have that structure, one obvious option is to create class-subfolders and put the images into them. Another option is to create a custom Dataset, see [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html).

Comment: The example link is now dead. I found pytorch's tutorial helpful: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html

Comment: @cacti5 thanks, I changed the link to the one that you found.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the error. I tried with different approach but resolving it only by creating a subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the approach to create subfolders of each class, separately for train/val/test, as expected by the ImageFolder to work very well. Here's a script that I created for my own usecase, you can modify it for your own

```
data_dir = '/content/data/oxford-102-flowers/'
files = ['train.txt','test.txt','valid.txt']

for i in files:
  with open(data_dir + i) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
      curr = i.split('.')[0]
      l = line.split()
      src = os.path.join(data_dir + l[0])

      dir = os.path.join(data_dir + curr)
      if not os.path.isdir(dir):
        os.mkdir(dir)
      
      sub_dir = os.path.join(dir + '/' + l[1])
      if not os.path.isdir(sub_dir):
        os.mkdir(sub_dir)

      os.system('cp "%s" "%s"' % (src, sub_dir))
print("All files copied to the subfolders")
```

I was working on the [Oxford-102-Dataset](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data/flowers/102/) and I had three .txt files for each of the train, validation and test set. The txt files contained the location and the name of the image (for eg: jpg/image_05038.jpg 58, where 58 represents the ground truth value of the actual class and 'jpg' was the source folder where all the images were stored)